# How can I add a row every time I call a method to write into an Excel file?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am a newbie to Apache POI and currently working on a project to write to Excel File.

I am having trouble how to insert a new row every time I call this method call "WriteInfo".
The result is that I write on the same row over again (because of line 2).

My code attempt is below:

```
public void writeInfo(Workbook workbook, Sheet sheet, MO temp) throws IOException {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(2);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(temp.getFirstName());
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(temp.getLastName());
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(temp.getAge());
        row.createCell(3).setCellValue(temp.getBirthDay());
        row.createCell(4).setCellValue(temp.getEmail());
        row.createCell(5).setCellValue(temp.getAddress());
        // Resize all columns to fit the content size
        for(int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
        }
        // Write the output to a file
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("poi-generated-file.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument to [`createRow()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createRow-int-) is the row number, so rather than hard-coding `2` there, you need to pass an ever-increasing row number to `createRow()`

```
private int currentRow = 2;

public void writeInfo(Workbook workbook, Sheet sheet, MO temp) throws IOException {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(currentRow++);
    ...
```

Comment: `static` seems like an especially bad idea here. Also, ALL_CAPS is used for constants, not variables.

Comment: Because the method it's being used in isn't static, it's an instance method.

Comment: Hey it worked thank you a lot. I did not know it would be this simple haha :)